# Rename a method added by a gem

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, sidekiq

I want to rename the `delay` method [added by the Sidekiq gem](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/extensions/class_methods.rb) to `sidekiq_delay`. This extension method is added to all classes in Ruby. How can I use Ruby meta-programming to do this?

I want to do this so Sidekiq's `delay` will not override Delay Job's `delay` method.

Comment: Why you want to do that? Does it conflict with your code? It's much easier and less risky to just change your code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I want to use delayed job at the same time, which also provides a 'delay' extension method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the relevant gem is included:

```
module Sidekiq::Extensions::Klass
  alias :sidekiq_delay :delay
  remove_method :delay
end
```

Comment: Sorry, may I add one more condition? I want Sidekiq's `delay` to be hidden, so it won't override DelayJob's `delay`. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that from the beginning.